# Why this attack formation for the mission?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun-maverick

For the final mission, Maverick strategizes that the mission be flown with 2 pairs of F-18s. One aircraft in each pair is a single seater and the other a twin seater.

What's the reason for selecting this configuration? Couldn't the pilot in a single seater F-18 laze the target effectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34691/f-a-18e-and-f-a-18f-rhinos-whats-the-difference

> First, for Fleet F-18Fs [the two seat variant], certain missions, such as flying as a Forward Air Controller require an additional flight officer to handle the workloads associated with the job and have a tactical control station specific to this work.

Comment: Thanks for finding this Todd. Although this doesn't answer why a single seater variant couldn't have performed that role instead.

Comment: @Sayan Because the mission role “require[s] an additional flight officer to handle the workloads”. The reason to have any single seaters is they are a little more agile for defending against interceptors

Comment: It seemed evident from Maverick's actions during his demonstration flight that he could do the piloting and lazing by himself.  Relying on a second plane to do the lazing seems like it'd increase the potential for failure.